# broadcast file to subscribers

Tags: xmpp, file-transfer, broadcast, openfire

i am using [pubsub protocol](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0060.html) for subscribing and publishing content , now i want to publish a file so that it will be automatically available for the users those who have subscribed.

i have explored other protocols to transfer file like

```
XEP-0096: SI File Transfer
XEP-0095: Stream Initiation
XEP-0047: In-Band Bytestreams
XEP-0065: SOCKS5 Bytestreams
```

but all the above file transfer protocols are one to one / peer to peer file transfer.

what i am looking for is once the publisher publish the file it will be available to all the subscribers just like the normal msg  we publish , so is there any way to achive this ?

Just the way `whtsapp` `chatON` and other messengers are sending multiple files to multifle contact

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the pubsub message to prompt a standard file transfer between the client and the server.

This would require the creation of a component on the server that you could upload the file to and use to do the file transfers.

A better option might be to do the file transfer outside of XMPP altogether.  Upload to a file server and then download from each client on receiving the message with the file info.

Comment: if we put the transfer outside of XMPP , dont you think it will take more time in uploading and downloading file ? these new messengers in market are transferring file this way ?

Comment: @Hunt peer to peer file transfer can be achieved using sockets which many new chat clients do

Comment: yeah but wht if the client is a web based client , how we gonna make socket connection there